# If it is known that $\lim _{h\to 0}(\frac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0))=0$, does this implies that $\lim _{h\to 0}(\frac{\frac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)}{h})=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

So I am working on a problem as such:

> Suppose that $f$ is a function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ exist for any real number $x$.
> Let $g$ be a function  with $g(0)\!=\!\!f'(0)$ and $g(x)\!=\!\!f(x)/x$
> for $x\neq0$. Given that $g(x)$ is continuous for any real number $x$,
> prove that $g'(x)$ exists for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

My approach to this problem is to divide the case into two case, which is for $x=0$ and $x\neq0$.

The function $g(x)$ can be written into a piecewise as such:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
      f(x)/x \;\;\;\;\;\; x\neq0 \\
      f'(0)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x=0
   \end{cases}$$

For $x\neq0$:
$$g(x)=f(x)/x$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)(x)+f(x)}{x^2}$$
Since $f'(x)$ exists for all real number $x$, this implies that $f(x)$ exists for all real number $x$. And since $x$ can never be $0$, then $g'(x)$ exists for all $x\neq0$.

**My question is for the case when $x\neq0$**

My approach is to use the definition of limit, which is to find out whether
$\;\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{g(0+h)-g(0)}h\;$ exists or no. If it does, then the limit exists.

Using what we know from the question,we can solve this equation:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)}{h}$$

And this is where my question comes from. Since we know that $g(x)$ is continous, we can say that $\;\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)\right)=0$.

But does this imply that $\;\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)}{h}=0\;$ and hence $g'(0)$ exists?

**I am thinking of using the L'Hopital rule for the case $\mathbf{0/0}$**, but is it appropriate in this problem? I have tried it but seems that it does not take me anywhere.

If no, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are probably missing a condition that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Also you should use the ratio $f(h) /h$ instead of $f'(h) /h$. I think this is a typo.

Comment: On further reading the condition $f(0)=0$ follows from continuity of $g(x)$ so no need to spell it out explicitly.

Comment: No. Take $f(x)=x^2$. Then $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)\right)=0$ but $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)}{h}\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the L'Hopital rule for the case $0/0$, indeed it is appropriate in this problem.

$g’(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{g(h)-g(0)}h=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{\frac{f(h)}h-f’(0)}h=$

$\qquad=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h)-f’(0)h}{h^2}\underset{\overbrace{\text{L’Hospital rule}}}{=}\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f’(h)-f’(0)}{2h}=$

$\qquad=\dfrac{f’’(0)}2\;.$